# Can I enter Italy with a receipt issued by an Italian post office for a residence permit application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, italy

I have a receipt issued by an Italian post office for my first residence permit, as well as a foreign passport with expired D visa.

Can I enter Italy with this?

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=it&SUBSECTION=AI&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines

> Residents of Italy holding **expired Residence Permits or a
>     copy of an expired Residence Permit**  are permitted to
>     re-enter Italy, provided also holding a **receipt issued by
>     the Italian Post Office** or Police Department, confirming new
>     permit has been applied for. Applications for renewal must
>     be made within 60 days of expiring, otherwise immigration
>     could refuse re-entry, even if holding confirmation of
>     application. Holders copies of an expired Residence Permit
>     also require a statement, stating that they are holding a
>     copy.

Since you're awaiting your first permit, this does not apply to you.

As such, if your nationality requires a visa to enter Italy for less than 90 days, **don't** leave Italy until you've received your permit. If you're already abroad, contact the Italian embassy where you are ***immediately***.